# I'm trying to add a Box to a JLayeredPane

Tags: jlayeredpane, box

> I declared the Box as: Box caja=Box.createHorizontalBox();
>   However the first layer the one that says FondoMenu.png is the only one showing and the Box doesnt show unless I put that JOptionPane showing it first, please some help (The BuscaImagen is a method I made that creates JLabel with my specifications)

```
capas.add(new BuscaImagen("FondoMenu.png", 0, 0), new Integer(0));
        caja.add(new BuscaImagen("JUGAR", "FIz.png", 2, 40, 90));
        caja.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        caja.add(new BuscaImagen("SALIR", "FDe.png", 2, 40, 240));
        caja.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        caja.add(new BuscaImagen("INSTRUCCIONES", "FAb.png", 2, 40, 390));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, caja);
        caja.setLocation(60, capas.getHeight() / 2 - 10);
        capas.add(caja, new Integer(1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice write up on oracle on how to use Layered Panes. I hope this helps with your issue
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html